# Ошибка установки dlib pip3.6

Tags: build-error

Всем привет! Хочу спросить, у меня возникла ошибка при установке dlib на raspberry pi 3, раньше я пробовал установить, просто зависало, потом как оказалось, нужно делать из под Python 3.6, я начал делать из под Python 3.6, И появилась теперь ошибка вместо зависания

`Building wheels for collected packages: dlib`

`Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error`

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:`

`command: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmp4c8_sgea`

Проблему я уже решил, но теперь тоже самое, просто зависает установка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]